# Hace horas estoy intentando usar Double.parseDouble pero no me deja una NumberFormatException

Tags: java

> Siempre uso esta instrucción tal cual me aparece. Escribo el Double.parseDouble y el elemento de tipo String, ya que las excepciones son un tema que aún no estoy viendo por lo que no las entiendo bien. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de evitar usarlo en esta ocasión, ya que supongo que debo estar cometiendo un error en algún otro lugar. Esto se supone que es una calculadora, y lo que estoy intentando hacer es pasar el texto del botón, que vendría a ser la pantalla, a una variable double, de esta forma simplemente me quedaría que la calculadora haga el resultado y lo imprima en el mismo botón. Pero primero necesito saber cómo solucionar ese problema.

```
public void PB(String r, ActionListener oyente) {
    
    JButton boton=new JButton(r);
    
    boton.addActionListener(oyente);
    
    LaminaC2.add(boton);
    
}

private class InsertaN implements ActionListener {
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        String entrada=e.getActionCommand();
        
        if(principio) {
            
            pantalla.setText("");
            principio=false;
            
        }
        
        pantalla.setText(pantalla.getText()+entrada);
        
    }
    
}

private class Operaciones implements ActionListener {
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        

        calcular(Double.parseDouble(pantalla.getText())); //Aquí me aparece la excepción.
        
        principio=true;
        
    }
    
    public void calcular(double x) {
        
        
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Y q es lo q pasa pones un numero y te da error?

Comment: Esa excepción corresponde a una conversión fallida a un tipo numérico. Deberías verificar que el texto que devuelve `pantalla.getText()` solo contenga números, de lo contrario seguirás teniendo esa excepción.

Comment: agrega el try catch correspondiente y verifica que getText realmente sea un numero con un print.

Answer (score 0):

verifica que solo este devolviendo números, esto lo puedes hacer con try catch o verificar que el texto solo tenga caracteres ascii del 48 al 57 y ademas el 46 (es el código del punto).
si despues de todo esto no funciona intenta usar `Float.parseFloat("");`

Answer (score 0):

getActionCommand() para button no funciona igual que en textField ya que en textField te retorna el texto pero en button te estará retornando la accion.

Por eso te da error por que estás tratando de convertir un valor que no es numérico a double

Verifica esta línea, puedes imprimir entrada y verificar que es lo contiene, te recomiendo que inicialices con 0.

```
     pantalla.setText(pantalla.getText()+entrada);
```